# Nesting multiple repos under one repo

Tags: git, github

For the past several days I've been trying to consolidate my class's assignment repos by nesting individually under a repo of the class name. Most of the resources I've found so far, or are suggested to me, are designed to merge two peer repos into one. This isn't what I want. My goal is to nest the assignment repos under a class repo both locally and remotely (and as I understand it; submodules would still be remotely distinct repos, which I don't want):

Now:

1. assignment 1 repo
2. assignment 2 repo
3. assignment 3 repo

Desired:

1. class repo

   - assignment 1 code, branches, commits
   - assignment 2 code, branches, commits
   - assignment 3 code, branches, commits

I attempted to use [this](https://medium.com/@checko/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-preserving-the-git-history-4e20d3fafa4e) article's instructions, repeating step #4 for assignment 2 & 3's repos, but only the `master` branch was pulled down, and when I run `~/class-repo/assignment-#-repo$ git pull`; an error is returned: `error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.`.

`~/class-repo$ git merge --continue` doesn't fix this, it returns: `error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files`.

`~/class-repo$ git fetch --all` hasn't pulled down all branches for each assignment repo.

How do I preserve the commits and branches of each assignment repo while nesting them in this fashion? I keep hitting brick walls, so if it's not possible to do, I understand.

Comment: Do you want the individual assignment repositories contained in subdirectories of the parent repository? If two assignment repositories contain branches with the same name, what do you expect the final repository to look like? Can you point us at the actual repositories involved, or are they private?

Comment: Are subdirectories the same as submodules? Aside from `main`, no branches have the same name(s). Will the class repo end up with all the assignment repo branches? They're private.

Comment: A subdirectory is just...a subdirectory. Sometimes people call them "folders" I guess. It's just a filesystem thing, not a git thing. I'm asking what you expect the final repository to look like. Also, how do you want to handle the multiple `main` branches?

Comment: Then to answer the original question; yes I want a dir with the classname, and 3 subdirectories each containing one (of three) assignment repo code, branches, and commits. I'm beginning to suspect it's not possible. As far as multiple main branches; ideally I'd have branch information limited to each subdirectory.

Comment: You cannot "limit branch information to each subdirectory"; branches exist at the repository level. The only way to do that is for each assignment repository to be a submodule (which is to stay, a standalone git repository with a reference in the parent repository). You can certainly structure a single repository the way you want, but your history will be the merged history of all three repositories.

Comment: Got it. I feared it wouldn't be possible. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what you want *is* possible, if you're willing to make a few compromises.  First, we can bundle everything into a single repository.

Let's assume I have three existing repositories `assignment1`, `assignment2`, and `assignment3`.

I can create an aggregate repository:

```
$ git init all-assignments
```

And then import the history of the three individual repositories into this aggregate:

```
$ cd all-assignments
$ git remote add work1 .../url/to/assignment1
$ git remote add work2 .../url/to/assignment2
$ git remote add work3 .../url/to/assignment3
$ git remote update
```

And then run this script to create local branches from all the remote branches:

```
git remote | while read remote; do
  git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/$remote/ |
  while read ref; do
    name=$(sed "s|refs/remotes/$remote/||" <<<"$ref")
    echo $name
    git branch $remote-$name $ref
  done
done
```

This gets us something like:

```
$ git branch
  work1-master
  work1-super-nifty-feature
  work2-master
  work2-update-before-final
  work3-main
  work3-quickstart
  work3-hackathon
```

We don't have the file organization you wanted, but we do have the repository histories all in a single place, and we can switch branches as necessary to see the content.

---

If you really want all the files in the same place at the same time, you can do something awful with `git subtree`. As above, add all the remotes and run `git remote update`, and then:

```
git remote | while read remote; do
    git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/$remote/ |
    while read ref; do
        name=$(sed "s|refs/remotes/$remote/||" <<<"$ref")
        echo $name
        git subtree add --prefix $remote/$name $ref
    done
done
```

This results in:

```
.
├── work1
│   └── master
│   └── super-nifty-feature
├── work2
│   ├── master
│   └── update-before-final
└── work3
    ├── main
    ├── quickstart
    └── hackathon
```

So now you have everything in one place, but it's all in the same branch, and each former branch now lives in its own directory.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to think about that. Thank you!